# Centos 7 - install and mount fc multipath disks

Tags: centos, fibre-channel, multipath

I tried to install multipathing on a Centos 7.5 host following some links like

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/dm_multipath/mpio_components

https://www.learnitguide.net/2016/06/how-to-configure-multipathing-in-linux.html

I fear I missed something as the output of "ssm list" states:

```
ssm list
--------------------------------------------------------------
Device          Free      Used      Total  Pool    Mount point
--------------------------------------------------------------
/dev/sda                        222.59 GB          PARTITIONED
/dev/sda1                         1.00 GB          /boot
/dev/sda2  167.58 GB  54.00 GB  221.58 GB  centos
/dev/sdb                        200.00 GB
/dev/sdc                        200.00 GB
/dev/sdd                          1.00 TB
/dev/sde                          1.00 TB
/dev/sdf                          1.17 TB
/dev/sdg                          1.17 TB
/dev/sdh                        200.00 GB
/dev/sdi                        200.00 GB
/dev/sdj                          1.00 TB
/dev/sdk                          1.00 TB
/dev/sdl                          1.17 TB
/dev/sdm                          1.17 TB
/dev/sdn                        200.00 GB
/dev/sdo                        200.00 GB
/dev/sdp                          1.00 TB
/dev/sdq                          1.00 TB
/dev/sdr                          1.17 TB
/dev/sds                          1.17 TB
/dev/sdt                        200.00 GB
/dev/sdu                        200.00 GB
/dev/sdv                          1.00 TB
/dev/sdw                          1.00 TB
/dev/sdx                          1.17 TB
/dev/sdy                          1.17 TB
--------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------
Pool    Type  Devices       Free      Used      Total
-----------------------------------------------------
centos  lvm   1        167.58 GB  54.00 GB  221.58 GB
-----------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Volume            Pool    Volume size  FS      FS size       Free  Type    Mount point
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/dev/centos/root  centos     50.00 GB  xfs    49.98 GB   47.89 GB  linear  /
/dev/centos/swap  centos      4.00 GB                              linear
/dev/sda1                     1.00 GB  xfs  1014.00 MB  732.00 MB  part    /boot
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Thought when installing dm-multipath the os hides the multiple /dev/sd* devices?

several outputs:

multipath -l:

```
3600a098038303561325d474f4b597539 dm-3 NETAPP  ,LUN C-Mode
size=1.0T features='4 queue_if_no_path pg_init_retries 50 retain_attached_hw_handle' hwhandler='1 alua' wp=rw
|-+- policy='service-time 0' prio=0 status=active
| |- 1:0:1:1 sdk 8:160  active undef unknown
| |- 1:0:3:1 sdw 65:96  active undef unknown
| |- 8:0:1:1 sdj 8:144  active undef unknown
| `- 8:0:2:1 sdp 8:240  active undef unknown
`-+- policy='service-time 0' prio=0 status=enabled
  |- 1:0:0:1 sde 8:64   active undef unknown
  |- 1:0:2:1 sdq 65:0   active undef unknown
  |- 8:0:0:1 sdd 8:48   active undef unknown
  `- 8:0:3:1 sdv 65:80  active undef unknown
san_disk1 (3600a098038303561325d474f4b59752d) dm-4 NETAPP  ,LUN C-Mode
size=1.2T features='4 queue_if_no_path pg_init_retries 50 retain_attached_hw_handle' hwhandler='1 alua' wp=rw
|-+- policy='service-time 0' prio=0 status=active
| |- 1:0:1:2 sdm 8:192  active undef unknown
| |- 1:0:3:2 sdx 65:112 active undef unknown
| |- 8:0:1:2 sdl 8:176  active undef unknown
| `- 8:0:2:2 sdr 65:16  active undef unknown
`-+- policy='service-time 0' prio=0 status=enabled
  |- 1:0:0:2 sdg 8:96   active undef unknown
  |- 1:0:2:2 sds 65:32  active undef unknown
  |- 8:0:0:2 sdf 8:80   active undef unknown
  `- 8:0:3:2 sdy 65:128 active undef unknown
3600a098038303561325d474f4b597538 dm-2 NETAPP  ,LUN C-Mode
size=200G features='4 queue_if_no_path pg_init_retries 50 retain_attached_hw_handle' hwhandler='1 alua' wp=rw
|-+- policy='service-time 0' prio=0 status=active
| |- 1:0:1:0 sdi 8:128  active undef unknown
| |- 1:0:3:0 sdu 65:64  active undef unknown
| |- 8:0:1:0 sdh 8:112  active undef unknown
| `- 8:0:2:0 sdn 8:208  active undef unknown
`-+- policy='service-time 0' prio=0 status=enabled
  |- 1:0:0:0 sdc 8:32   active undef unknown
  |- 1:0:2:0 sdo 8:224  active undef unknown
  |- 8:0:0:0 sdb 8:16   active undef unknown
  `- 8:0:3:0 sdt 65:48  active undef unknown
```

multipath -ll

```
3600a098038303561325d474f4b597539 dm-3 NETAPP  ,LUN C-Mode
size=1.0T features='4 queue_if_no_path pg_init_retries 50 retain_attached_hw_handle' hwhandler='1 alua' wp=rw
|-+- policy='service-time 0' prio=50 status=active
| |- 1:0:1:1 sdk 8:160  active ready running
| |- 1:0:3:1 sdw 65:96  active ready running
| |- 8:0:1:1 sdj 8:144  active ready running
| `- 8:0:2:1 sdp 8:240  active ready running
`-+- policy='service-time 0' prio=10 status=enabled
  |- 1:0:0:1 sde 8:64   active ready running
  |- 1:0:2:1 sdq 65:0   active ready running
  |- 8:0:0:1 sdd 8:48   active ready running
  `- 8:0:3:1 sdv 65:80  active ready running
san_disk1 (3600a098038303561325d474f4b59752d) dm-4 NETAPP  ,LUN C-Mode
size=1.2T features='4 queue_if_no_path pg_init_retries 50 retain_attached_hw_handle' hwhandler='1 alua' wp=rw
|-+- policy='service-time 0' prio=50 status=active
| |- 1:0:1:2 sdm 8:192  active ready running
| |- 1:0:3:2 sdx 65:112 active ready running
| |- 8:0:1:2 sdl 8:176  active ready running
| `- 8:0:2:2 sdr 65:16  active ready running
`-+- policy='service-time 0' prio=10 status=enabled
  |- 1:0:0:2 sdg 8:96   active ready running
  |- 1:0:2:2 sds 65:32  active ready running
  |- 8:0:0:2 sdf 8:80   active ready running
  `- 8:0:3:2 sdy 65:128 active ready running
3600a098038303561325d474f4b597538 dm-2 NETAPP  ,LUN C-Mode
size=200G features='4 queue_if_no_path pg_init_retries 50 retain_attached_hw_handle' hwhandler='1 alua' wp=rw
|-+- policy='service-time 0' prio=50 status=active
| |- 1:0:1:0 sdi 8:128  active ready running
| |- 1:0:3:0 sdu 65:64  active ready running
| |- 8:0:1:0 sdh 8:112  active ready running
| `- 8:0:2:0 sdn 8:208  active ready running
`-+- policy='service-time 0' prio=10 status=enabled
  |- 1:0:0:0 sdc 8:32   active ready running
  |- 1:0:2:0 sdo 8:224  active ready running
  |- 8:0:0:0 sdb 8:16   active ready running
  `- 8:0:3:0 sdt 65:48  active ready running
```

cat /etc/multipath.conf
       defaults {
         user_friendly_names yes
         #path_grouping_policy multibus
         find_multipaths yes
         path_grouping_policy failover
    }

```
 blacklist {
    devnode "sda"
}

 multipaths {
    multipath {
            wwid 3600a098038303561325d474f4b59752d
            alias san_disk1
    }
}
```

service multipathd status

```
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status multipathd.service
● multipathd.service - Device-Mapper Multipath Device Controller
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/multipathd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2018-07-09 12:12:27 CEST; 2min 19s ago
  Process: 19275 ExecStart=/sbin/multipathd (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 19272 ExecStartPre=/sbin/multipath -A (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 19268 ExecStartPre=/sbin/modprobe dm-multipath (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 19277 (multipathd)
    Tasks: 9
   CGroup: /system.slice/multipathd.service
           └─19277 /sbin/multipathd

Jul 09 12:12:27 VIGT01-101.res01.ads.ooe.local systemd[1]: Starting Device-Mapper Multipath Device Controller...
Jul 09 12:12:27 VIGT01-101.res01.ads.ooe.local systemd[1]: Started Device-Mapper Multipath Device Controller.
Jul 09 12:12:27 VIGT01-101.res01.ads.ooe.local multipathd[19277]: 3600a098038303561325d474f4b597538: load table [0 419430400 multipath 4 queue_if_no_path pg...65:48 1]
Jul 09 12:12:27 VIGT01-101.res01.ads.ooe.local multipathd[19277]: 3600a098038303561325d474f4b597539: load table [0 2147518464 multipath 4 queue_if_no_path p...65:80 1]
Jul 09 12:12:27 VIGT01-101.res01.ads.ooe.local multipathd[19277]: san_disk1: load table [0 2516901888 multipath 4 queue_if_no_path pg_init_retries 50 retain...5:128 1]
Jul 09 12:12:27 VIGT01-101.res01.ads.ooe.local multipathd[19277]: 3600a098038303561325d474f4b597538: event checker started
Jul 09 12:12:27 VIGT01-101.res01.ads.ooe.local multipathd[19277]: 3600a098038303561325d474f4b597539: event checker started
Jul 09 12:12:27 VIGT01-101.res01.ads.ooe.local multipathd[19277]: san_disk1: event checker started
Jul 09 12:12:27 VIGT01-101.res01.ads.ooe.local multipathd[19277]: path checkers start up
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Comment: Why multipath could hide the sdx devices?

Answer (score 1):

It's OK. The underlying devices are not being hidden in any way.